# .Ajax call not returning my List object as JSON in ASP.NET MVC 5, getting error 500 : Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

Please can someone have a loot at my code, to see if something doesn't make sense. I'm simply trying return a List object as Json object from a action method in a controller using ajax, but for some reason I'm getting the error in the picture below. I've tried everything but can't seem to find the problem.

Ajax call

```
var ReservationsViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

self.reservations = ko.observableArray();
self.loading = ko.observable(true);


    $.ajax({
            url:'ReservationsOfSelectedDay',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {
                self.reservations(data);
                self.loading(false);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
            }
       });
}



$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
});
```

Controller Action

```
 public JsonResult ReservationsOfSelectedDay()
    {
        List<BistroReservations_Reservation> ReservationsPerDay = new List<BistroReservations_Reservation>();

        ReservationsPerDay = db.BistroReservations_Reservations.ToList();


        return Json(ReservationsPerDay,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Error

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP status 500: Internal Server Error indicates that something went wrong in your controller, or in invoking your controller.  The most common cause is your controller action code throwing an Exception.

Either use the debugger to step through your controller, or add some exception handling and log the exception details.  If your controller is never invoked, you are not calling the correct URL.

In particular look at `db`.  The most common pattern (and the one I recommend) is to get a new instance of your DbContext for each call to a controller action.  Perhaps `db` is not initialized.